# How to get data from data base with asp mvc 4 async controller and EntityFramework 6 async read from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, async-await, c#-5.0

I have next controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ImageAsync(int id)
{
    var img = await _repository.GetImageAsync(id);
    if (img != null)
    {
        return File(img, "image/jpg"); //View(img);
    }
    byte[] res = new byte[0];
    return File(res, "image/jpg");
}
```

and method in repository

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetImage(int imageId)
{
    try
    {
        var dbCtx = new smartbags_storeEntities();

        var res = await dbCtx.GoodImages.SingleAsync(d => d.ImageId == imageId);
        return res != null ? res.ImageData : null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}

public async Task<byte[]> GetImageAsync(int imageId)
{
    byte[] img = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var res = GetImage(imageId).Result;
        if (res != null)
        {
            var wi = new System.Web.Helpers.WebImage(res);

            wi.AddTextWatermark("info");

            return wi.GetBytes();
        }
        return null;
    });

    return img;
}
```

but execution of image reading is freezing on line

```
var res = await dbCtx.GoodImages.SingleAsync(d => d.ImageId == imageId);
```

What I am doing in wrong way when try to read data from data base in async style ?

Comment: It's funny how often this same issue trips people. 10 questions a week at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to the property `Result` of a `Task` is a blocking call and the continuation of the `await` won't be able to be posted to run.

Once you already have a Task returning method, why didn't you just use `await`?

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetImageAsync(int imageId)
{
    var res = await GetImage(imageId);
    if (res != null)
    {
        var wi = new System.Web.Helpers.WebImage(res);
        wi.AddTextWatermark("info");

        return wi.GetBytes();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The funny thing about that line is that it calls `SingleAsync`, which is a TAP extension method for *observables*.

I have never used a data repository that exposed its collections as observables, though I suppose it is *possible*. My first guess is that [the task returned by] `SingleAsync` isn't completing because the `GoodImages` observable isn't completing. Note that `SingleAsync` must continue scanning after it sees a match to ensure that it is the *only* match; `FirstAsync` is more forgiving and will complete as soon as it sees the first match.

On a side note, I do recommend using `await` instead of `Result` and not using `Task.Run` on the server. So [Paulo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18047946/263693) is good in that regard, though in this case `Result` is *not* causing a deadlock.

Comment: I believe EF 6 has async support through extensions like SingleAsync.

Comment: Single and First have different intentions and none is better or worth than the other. You should know when to use one or the other based on your intentions. (http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2010/03/28/linq-single-vs-first.aspx).